# Using liblinphone 4.x in my ios swift project

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, linphone

How do I use liblinphone 4.x in a swift project?

I am building an app to make voip calls and the best open source sdk i found was [liblinphone](http://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/liblinphone). I have followed [this](https://wiki.linphone.org/xwiki/wiki/public/view/Lib/Getting%20started/iOS/) and successfully added liblinphone to my project. My challenge now is using the import `linphonesw'. I am new to iOS. I need

- Listeners for Incoming call, Registration state and Call state
- Methods to register, initiate a call, hang up and accept call

I have tried [this](https://github.com/cwliu/linphone-swift-demo/blob/master/linphone-trial/LinphoneManager.swift) but it seems it needs liblinphone 3.x which i am having a challenge to add that to my project. The project is a flutter generated one in which I will use these methods via platform channels.

Comment: You can try this: https://github.com/hamzaozturk/linphone-swift-demo